# Tree traversing doesn't print desired solution

Tags: java, oop, tree

(java)

I have class called **Node**, which has following fields:

1. value (integer)
2. connectedNodes (array of **Node** objects, always has same size = 2)
3. combination (object of **Combination** class)

Combination class has one field called **messageContext**, let's just say that it's a message which needs to be shown on the screen when something happens (described later).

Also, we have one **Tree** object, which has only one field: root (**Node** object)

Now, let's say that we have one String called **combinationStr** = "1121". Now, we use **Tree**'s method called **addCombination**:

```
public void addCombination(Combination finalCombination, Node current, String combination, int counter) {

    if(counter==combination.length()) {
        return;
    }

    int value = combination.charAt(counter)-48;
    if(current.connectedNodes[value-1]==null) {
        current.connectedNodes[value-1] = new Node(value);
    }
    if(counter==combination.length()-1) {
        current.combination = finalCombination;
        return;
    }
    addCombination(finalCombination,current.connectedNodes[value-1],combination,counter+1);

}
```

**finalCombination** object is an object that is going to be assigned to the last **Node**'s **combination** field, added to the Tree for one **combinationStr**. So, we use this function to create the Tree-like structure that has path: -1 (root) -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1
When we come to the last one, traversing the **Tree**, we should see message appear. This is the **messageContext** of **finalCombination**.

Okay so, now let's use **while(true)** loop that will let us input a number, which will be like a path-chooser. If we input 1, we will go to node 1 and have other options to choose.

While loop looks like this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node currentNode = tree.root;
    while(true) {
        for(Node node: currentNode.connectedNodes) {
            if(node!=null) {
                System.out.print(node.value + " ");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print("nullnode ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        if(currentNode.combination!=null) {
            System.out.println(currentNode.combination.messageContext);
        }
        if(currentNode.connectedNodes[0]==null && currentNode.connectedNodes[1]==null) {
            currentNode = tree.root;
            System.out.println("root");
        }
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        currentNode = tree.takeStep(currentNode,x);
    }
```

So, what are we doing here is actually printing the value of current Node, then printing values of Node's we can go to. If Node doesn't exist, we print **nullnode**. 
The **takeStep()** method looks like this:

```
public Node takeStep(Node current, int value) {
    if(current.connectedNodes[value-1]!=null) {
        return current.connectedNodes[value-1];
    }
    return this.root;
}
```

It just checks if there is a node we want to go to and returns that node, if it does. If it doesn't exist, it will return us to root.

But, what's the problem with this code ?

Well, look at the whole main class:

```
    Tree tree = new Tree(new Node(-1));
    String[] combination = {"1121","11","2212"};
    for(String s: combination) {
        Combination tempCombination = new Combination();
        tempCombination.messageContext = s + " ova poruka";
        tree.addCombination(tempCombination,tree.root,s,0);
        tree.traverse(tree.root);
        System.out.println("END");
    }

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node currentNode = tree.root;

    while(true) {
        System.out.println(currentNode.value);
        for(Node node: currentNode.connectedNodes) {
            if(node!=null) {
                System.out.print(node.value + " ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("nullnode ");
            }
        }
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        if(currentNode.combination!=null) {
            System.out.println(currentNode.combination.messageContext);
            if(currentNode.connectedNodes[0]==null && currentNode.connectedNodes[1]==null) {
                currentNode = tree.root;
                break;
            }
        }
        currentNode = tree.takeStep(currentNode,x);
    }
```

When we enter number x, we will call **takeStep** and check if that node exists connected to current one. But the problem is: When we input 1, it prints everything normally, when we input 1 again, it prints everything normally, when we input 2, it prints everything normally... but when we input 1 again, it says there are 2 nullnodes, and for some reason it doesn't change to root. Can anyone help me please? Here are the full classes:

**NODE:**

```
public class Node {
    int value;
    Node[] connectedNodes = {null,null};
    Combination combination;

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.combination = null;
    }
}
```

**TREE:**

```
public class Tree {
    Node root;

    public Tree(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public void addCombination(Combination finalCombination, Node current, String combination, int counter) {

        if(counter==combination.length()) {
            return;
        }

    int value = combination.charAt(counter)-48;
    if(current.connectedNodes[value-1]==null) {
        current.connectedNodes[value-1] = new Node(value);
    }
    if(counter==combination.length()-1) {
        current.combination = finalCombination;
        return;
    }
    addCombination(finalCombination,current.connectedNodes[value-1],combination,counter+1);

}

public void traverse(Node current) {
    System.out.print(current.value+ " ");
    for(Node node: current.connectedNodes) {
        if(node!=null) {
            traverse(node);
        }
    }
}

public Node takeStep(Node current, int value) {
    if(current.connectedNodes[value-1]!=null) {
        return current.connectedNodes[value-1];
    }
    return this.root;
}}
```

**COMBINATION**:

```
public class Combination {
     String messageContext;
}
```

Can you please help me ? I just want to reset to root when it hasn't anywhere to go else ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and found out that you are storing the **message context** in the parent node instead of the actual node which marks the end of the combination. So I changed this piece of code in **addCombination**.

```
    public void addCombination(Combination finalCombination, Node current, String combination, int counter) {

    if (counter == combination.length()) {
        //Storing at the original node.
        current.combination = finalCombination;
        return;
    }

    int value = combination.charAt(counter) - 48;
    if (current.connectedNodes[value - 1] == null) {
        current.connectedNodes[value - 1] = new Node(value);
    }
    addCombination(finalCombination, current.connectedNodes[value - 1], combination, counter + 1);

}
```

And changed following in the main code.

```
 while (true) {
        System.out.println(currentNode.value);
        //Moved it up now as the node it self has the message context.
        if (currentNode.combination != null) {
            System.out.println(currentNode.combination.messageContext);
            if (currentNode.connectedNodes[0] == null && currentNode.connectedNodes[1] == null) {
                currentNode = tree.root;
                continue;
            }
        }
        for (Node node : currentNode.connectedNodes) {
            if (node != null) {
                System.out.print(node.value + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("nullnode ");
            }
        }
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        currentNode = tree.takeStep(currentNode, x);
    }
```

Now try the code it is resetting to root as expected.